# Show that $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 4$ has no solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

As the title says, I've been asked to show that the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3 = 4$ has no solutions for any integers $x$, $y$, and $z$.

I'm a bit stuck on where to start, so I'd appreciate any help or hints. Thanks!

Comment: Hanc marginis exiguitas non caperet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\;x^3\!\pmod{9}$ can be only $0$ or $\pm 1$, hence the sum of three cubes cannot be a number of the form $9k\pm 4$.

There is a [well-known conjecture](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/integers-equal-to-the-sum-of-three-cubes/) stating that every integer number $\not\equiv\pm 4\pmod{9}$ can be expressed as the sum of three cubes, and every integer number $\equiv 4\pmod{9}$ can be expressed as the sum of four cubes.

Comment: Quite helpful, thank you!

Comment: And I think, the first unknown case here is $x^3+y^3+z^3=33$. For $x^3+y^3+z^3=30$ Beck et al found $x=2220422932$, $y=-2218888517$ and $z=-283059965$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $x^3 + y^3 +z^3$ has solution: $x= 8866128975287528, y=-8778405442862239$, and $z=-2736111468807040$

Comment: @TranTu Yes, of course $33$ is the sum of three cubes. But this was only found in $2019$. This post is from $2015$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491460/is-there-any-important-question-in-mathematics-answered-in-2019/3491466#3491466) for an update.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry for the late reply. I don't look at the date of your post