# Is there any important question in mathematics answered in 2019?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Is there any important question in mathematics answered in 2019?

Comment: This may be a bit too opinion-based, imo.

Comment: "Most" might be opinion based, but a big list question of important achievements through the year could be interesting.

Comment: I think if there was some important open question which was solved in 2019 it can be called "the most important achievement" :)

Comment: @WillJagy I am puzzled by why you made that edit or why you think this improves the question.

Comment: @YiFan I wouldn't say improved. Beginning about 1978, there was a radio show in England called The Hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy. One of the particularly funny parts is an account of how a civilization waited seven million years for a computer tells them the answer to what they asked it, the big question of life, the Universe, and Everything. After all that time passes, the computer tells the descendants that it has an answer but they probably won't like it. They want to know anyway;  the computer tells them the Answer is 42. The article in Dietrich's answer used language recalling that.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I know the reference, however I do not feel the edit appropriate despite the humour. If you don't mind, I have taken the liberty to rollback the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following achievement made it to the newspapers in $2019$: *Mathematicians Solve '42' Problem With Planetary Supercomputer*, i.e.,
$$
 (-80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3 = 42
$$
is a representation of $42$ as sum of three cubes.

I do not claim that this is "a most important achievement", but certainly a popular one.

References: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes)

Comment: Good one! Thanks! :)

Comment: +1; the reference you linked says the case $n=33$ was also solved in $2019$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner "The number 42 is, famously, the answer to the question of life, the universe and everything in the Hitchhikers' Guide to the Galaxy."